# Has anyone got this error before: The context `__THEMING__` is marked as required in `Jss(StatelessNotificationProvider)`, but its value is `undefined

Tags: material-ui

After upgrading the Material-ui version from v3 to v4, it is throwing an error message.
Also I'm getting another error: Error: [undefined] Please use ThemeProvider to be able to use WithTheme. Although I'm not using any WithTheme from Material-ui.
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH5Xq.png)

App.tsx

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <BrowserRouter>
  <App />
 </BrowserRouter>,
 document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

Index.tsx

```
const jss = create(jssPreset());

jss
.createStyleSheet({
'@global': { ...globalStyles },
})
.attach();

export const createSATheme = (opts?: {}) => 
createMuiTheme(merge(defaultTheme as object, opts)) as Theme;

export interface ProviderProps {
children?: ReactNode;
theme?: Theme | null;
}

const { NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const isTest = NODE_ENV === 'test';

let providerReferenceCount = 0;

const UIProvider = ({ children, theme }: ProviderProps) => {
let classNameReferenceCount = 0;
const generateClassName = isTest
? (rule, styleSheet) => 
`test-${styleSheet.options.classNamePrefix}-
${rule.key}-${classNameReferenceCount++}`
: createGenerateClassName({
  productionPrefix: `c${providerReferenceCount++}-`,
});
return (
<JssProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme || createSATheme()}>
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
</JssProvider>
);
};

export { UIProvider };
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.